# Compare Columns of genes in file and output the gene and number of column it is present in linux

Tags: linux, text-processing, columns, bioinformatics

I have 3 coumns of genes in a file like this

```
col1    col2    col3
CXCL9   CXCL9   CXCL9
MAP2K6  MAP2K6  MAP2K6
CXCL10  CXCL10  CXCL11
```

I want to match the 3 columns and see which gene is present in how many columns, The output desired is in the format as

```
CXCL9 3
MAP2K6 3
CXCL10 2
CXCL11 1
```

Can somebody help me, it would save me a lot of time

Comment: Is this homework? See https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344/homework-policy-proposal

Comment: is the line `col1    col2    col3` really appears as the header line in your file?

Answer (score 1):

**`sed`** + **`sort`** + **`uniq`** solution:

```
sed 's/[[:space:]]\+/\n/g' file | sort | uniq -c
```

The output:

```
  2 CXCL10
  1 CXCL11
  3 CXCL9
  3 MAP2K6
```

Comment: What about the col1, col2, col3 headings?

Comment: @MukeshSaiKumar, I suppose that they were just for demonstration purpose

Comment: . . . perhaps `sed -n '1!s/[[:space:]]\+/\n/gp'` ?

Answer (score 0):

If there are no spaces between the names of genes, and the names of the columns follow the pattern you gave, then you may use this following script as a hint:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `cat genes.txt`; do
    [[ $i == "col"* ]] || echo $i;
done | sort | uniq -c
```

Answer (score 0):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[$i]++ }END{ for(i in a) print i, a[i] }' file
```

The output:

```
CXCL11 1
MAP2K6 3
CXCL9 3
CXCL10 2
```